# sqlite: Как вносить из списка в таблицу каждое значение с новой строки

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть список из нескольких имен: [маша, вася, петя, коля] как мне передать это в табличку и чтобы каждое новое имя писалось в новой строке? Получается передать, но он всех в одну строчку сохраняет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас уже есть готовая таблица sqlite. Воспользуйтесь циклом :

```
import sqlite3

user_l = ["маша", "вася", "петя", "коля"]

class UserDb:
    def __init__(self, db_file='имя файла'):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def add_user(self, user_list):
        for i in user_list:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO имя_таблицы (имя_колонки) VALUES (?);", (i,))

        self.conn.commit()

UserDb = UserDb()
UserDb.add_user(user_l)
```

Comment: Не подумал о цикле, спасибо за помощь)